# How do we calculate statistics on data weighted by relative frequencies?

Tags: weights, weighted-data

I have the following data with some values and their corresponding weights.

| groups | values | weights |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 0.25 |
| a | 3 | 0.75 |
| b | 8 | 1.00 |

The weights represent **relative frequencies** of each value in the group provided that all the weights of the same group will always sum up to 1.

---

I have recently proven that we could not simply:

1. Adjust the weights (multiply every weight by a scalar to turn them into integers)
2. Duplicate the observations according to their weights
3. Calculate weighted statistics based on the duplicated values
4. And hopefully it would give a correct result with statistics like `mean`, `median`, `var`, `std`, etc. on each group

> The original weights $[0.25, 0.75, 1.00]$ would become $[1, 3, 4]$ after adjustment by multiplying every weight by $4$.
>
> After adjusting and duplicating, our data would look like this.
>
> | groups | values | weights |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | a | 1 | 1 |
> | a | 3 | 3 |
> | a | 3 | 3 |
> | a | 3 | 3 |
> | b | 8 | 4 |
> | b | 8 | 4 |
> | b | 8 | 4 |
> | b | 8 | 4 |

The reason is this does not work is because the more we duplicate observations, the smaller some statistics like `var` and `std` become. Here is a comparison of the same statistics on non-duplicated and duplicated values respectively.

|  | $[1, 5, 3, 7]$ | $[1, 5, 3, 7, 1, 5, 3, 7]$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| mean | 4.0 | 4.0 |
| median | 4.0 | 4.0 |
| std | 2.581989 | 2.390457 |
| var | 6.666667 | 5.714286 |
| skew | 0.0 | 0.0 |
| kurt | -1.2 | -1.456 |

Duplication of quantities heavily affects certain types of statistics like variance and standard deviation.

However, this leads to another question:

> Would it ever be possible to calculate accurate statistics based on values weighted by **relative frequencies**?

Because they are **relative frequencies**, the furthest we can get is **relative statistics**. For example, we can say "the variance of Group A is higher than the variance of Group B" but not "the variance of Group A is $[\dots]$ and the variance of Group B is $[\dots]$"

I have also noticed that the number of observations in each group would be the same, and specifically, that number of observations is equal to the scalar that we previously picked, which makes comparisons between groups even fairer.

This is an odd problem because I have never worked with frequencies that are not integers before so please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Means and coeffeixints related to them  will be okay but variances / standard errors of estimated quantities would be too small.

Comment: Different kinds of weighting are in use.  (Stata recognizes three different ones and provides for a user-defined fourth method.)  Please, then, explain what your weights *mean* and what you hope these weighted statistics will *represent* or be interpreted.

Comment: @whuber This question was originally asked on Stack Overflow, you can refer to [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69783742/16936415) for more information about the author's intents on weights.

Comment: Please include all relevant information in this post here, too.

Comment: @whuber Thank you for pointing out the fact that there are different types of weights. I will let the author clarify which type of weights he is working with.

Comment: OKay.  But *you* are the one asking the question here, so surely you are in the best position to explain to us which weights *you* are considering!

Comment: @whuber Hello! I have updated my post and stated that these weights are **relative frequency** weights. Do you have any critiques on my hypothesis or even an approach to deal with this?

Comment: You can compute any statistic that does not require the total count (sample size).  That would include any moment (mean, variance, etc) as well as quantiles but not, for example, a standard error.

Comment: @whuber Now I got it. Thank you.